# Lightning Out : Uncaught ReferenceError: $A is not defined when user is not logged in

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, lightning-out

I want to use my **LWC**'in an External Site (Heroku).  For it I use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out).

I have built a simple **Aura Application** (in my **Sandbox**) according to documentation here : [Lightning Out Dependencies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out_dependencies)

```html
<aura:application access="Global"  extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:testLWC"/>
</aura:application>
```

I have implemented the **OAuth** using *[JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5)* auth (based on this great video : [Implementing a JWT Server to Server OAuth between Salesforce and Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5OZZsVkOKY&t=2915s) ).
The *main* method (which connects to **Lightning Out**) in the **Heroku**  :

```js
let renderLightningOutComponent = (token) => {
    $Lightning.use(
        "c:LightningOutDemo", 
        function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:testLWC", 
                {},
                "testLWC",
                function(cmp) { /* ToDo */}
            );
        },
        "https://{my-domain}.lightning.force.com",
        token
    )
};
```

**-- ERROR --**

If my user is NOT **logged in** **Salesforce**, I get next errors in **JS Console** :

[image]

And the **Network** :

[image]

It works **without** the problems if a users is **logged in** !

So as I understand the `$Lightning.use()` method **fails** for some reason when a user is **not logged in** the Sandbox.
As I see it tries to load some resource as *app.css*, *aura_prod.js* etc.

**IMPORTANT :**
I do **NOT** have this issue if I try to connect to my **Developer org** .

Is there is something that I am missing ?

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Comment: Have you tried adding implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess" to you Aura component to check if unauthenticated users can log in?

Comment: @KostadinStoev thanks for the comment, Yes I did try it. No difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with Enhanced Domains. (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced.htm&type=5)

Enabling enhanced domains adds a .sandbox. to the URL,  which is causing a few problems with Lightning Out.

I recommend disabling Enhanced Domain in the Sandbox so you can use/test it.

Production and Dev Orgs don't have the .sandbox. part added to the URLs which is why it works correctly there.

Comment: Thank you, with enhanced domains turned off it works correct.